# Prononciation du mot « exercice »

Tags: prononciation

Le mot « exercice » est censé être prononcé /εgzεrsis/. Mais j'entends très souvent la prononciation /egzεrsis/. Je voudrais donc savoir : pourquoi on entend les deux prononciations, et laquelle est correcte ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le choix est libre, les deux prononciations sont courantes bien qu'il me semble que la variante en /e/ soit plus fréquente.

Jamais personne ne te reprendra ou ne se rendra compte de quoi que ce soit que tu prononces l'une ou l'autre.

En revanche, quand *EX* termine un mot (*lat**ex***) ou est suivi par une consonne (***ex**cellent*), le *E* est beaucoup plus souvent (toujours?) ouvert : /εks/.